# How to use Chrome's CRL sets (or some master CRL list) as a CRL file?

Tags: openssl, curl, google-chrome, crl

I am looking for a master CRL list. The closest thing I have found is the Chromium project's [CRLSets](http://dev.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/crlsets). I used [crlset-tools](https://github.com/agl/crlset-tools) to get the crlset (`crlset fetch > crl-set`) and then dumped the serial numbers (`crlset dump crl-set`) so I see something like this:

```
f24196ae94078667348f02e8e37458a3a6e6aad1e0b0dc610118cce721427bfc
  03fb3b4d35074e
  03fbf94a0e6c39
  04097214d6c97c
  0442c6b3face55
  ....
```

I want to be able to pass to openssl or curl (which uses openssl) a CRL file containing a master list of all bad serials. For example rather than just passing in verisign's crl, I want everything passed in. I thought I could do this with crlset but I don't think the format is compatible. I tried `openssl crl -inform DER -text -in crl-set` but it says:

```
unable to load CRL
5532:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag:tasn_dec.c:
1319:
5532:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error:ta
sn_dec.c:381:Type=X509_CRL
```

If anyone has any ideas on how to do what I'm talking about or any creative way to do this please let me know. Thanks

Comment: The format of the file from crlset is not compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be possible, at least in the form that you'd like.

Consider that in Chrome's CRLsets, there are (possibly) multiple revoked certificates from *multiple* CAs.  A single CRL file which contains certificate from *multiple* CAs is known as an "indirect CRL".  Indirect CRLs are poorly supported; see [here](http://openssl.6102.n7.nabble.com/Handling-Indirect-CRL-Issuer-td24161.html) and [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/91684/96204); OpenSSL may not be able to do this.

In addition, as @bentek mentions, it looks like the CRLsets format is not compatible.  Specifically, the CRLsets format does not contain all of the necessary CRL fields; see [RFC 5280, Section 5.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-5.1).  CRLsets contains (per its documentation) the SHA-256 hash of the Subject Public Key Info for the issuing certs, and the certificate serial numbers for revoked certificates from that issuing cert.  There is not enough information to reconstruct a *direct* CRL (*i.e.* one CRL file per CA), sadly, if we wanted to.  The biggest lack/omission, IMHO, is the *name* (DN) of the issuer of the revoked cert.  CRLsets gives us a "fingerprint" (the SHA-256 SPKI hash), but mapping that fingerprint to the DN of the cert in question, given the scope of the Internet, would not be an easy task.